# Bardic Masterpiece--Triple Time on mounts?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement, bard

So, the title says it all, can I use my Triple Time Masterpiece to increase my and my allies mount speed? Are our mounts considered allies when in the context of this masterpieces description?

Comment: Related: [what is/n't an ally?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77641/what-is-nt-an-ally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the responses to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77641/what-is-nt-an-ally), the consensus on this board (at least a year ago) seems to be that mounts would count. In particular the designation that most people seem to favor is that anyone/thing that would want to receive the benefit and is capable of making that decision (such as a mount that has been trained to ride and/or fight with you) can count as an ally.

Comment: The top answer actually states anyone the player wants and no one they don't, which is significantly different, but still allows mounts.